# Google charts tools Stacked chart

Tags: graph, charts

I'm new to Google Charts tools and I was wondering what I'am doing wrong. I want to make the BarChart (or ColumnChart) stacked by adding 'isStacked':true but then the chart gives me wrong data.

[You can try it yourself on the Google playground with this code](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#bar_chart)

(Just add 'isStacked':true to the options to see the wrong results)

```
function drawVisualization() {
// Create and populate the data table.
var  data = new  google.visualization.DataTable({"cols":[{"id":"","label":"Date","type":"string"},
                                                     {"id":"","label":"Complaints","type":"number"},
                                                     {"id":"","label":"Compliments","type":"number"},
                                                     {"id":"","label":"Questions","type":"number"},
                                                     {"id":"","label":"Suggestions","type":"number"}],
                                             "rows":[{"c":[{"v":"12\/2011"},{"v":30},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},
                                                     {"c":[{"v":"1\/2012"},{"v":93},{"v":"5"},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},
                                                     {"c":[{"v":"2\/2012"},{"v":82},{"v":"5"},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},
                                                     {"c":[{"v":"3\/2012"},{"v":72},{"v":"10"},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},
                                                     {"c":[{"v":"4\/2012"},{"v":68},{"v":"8"},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},
                                                     {"c":[{"v":"5\/2012"},{"v":59},{"v":"7"},{"v":0},{"v":0}]},
                                                     {"c":[{"v":"6\/2012"},{"v":30},{"v":"3"},{"v":"3"},{"v":0}]},
                                                     {"c":[{"v":"7\/2012"},{"v":37},{"v":"3"},{"v":"4"},{"v":"3"}]},
                                                     {"c":[{"v":"8\/2012"},{"v":31},{"v":"2"},{"v":"5"},{"v":0}]},
                                                     {"c":[{"v":"9\/2012"},{"v":47},{"v":"2"},{"v":"1"},{"v":"1"}]},
                                                     {"c":[{"v":"10\/2012"},{"v":67},{"v":0},{"v":"5"},{"v":"1"}]},
                                                     {"c":[{"v":"11\/2012"},{"v":38},{"v":"1"},{"v":"4"},{"v":0}]},
                                                     {"c":[{"v":"12\/2012"},{"v":14},{"v":"1"},{"v":"1"},{"v":"1"}]}
                                                    ]});       


// Create and draw the visualization.
new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
  draw(data,
       {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
        width:1000, height:400,
        vAxis: {title: "Year"},
        hAxis: {title: "Cups"}}
  );
}
```

I hope somebody can help me...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the very same problem. The solution is, numeric values should NOT be between quotation marks, otherwise "3"+"4" becomes 34 instead of 7.

Just remove the " marks if there's a numeric value there.
cheers, greg

UPDATE: if you use 'f:' values as well, you will need the quotation marks again, otherwise mouseover might not work on the chart.

```
{"c":[{"v":"12\/2012"},{"v":14, "f":"14"},{"v":1, "f":"1"},{"v":1, "f":"1"},{"v":1, "f":"1"}]}
```